# Difference between @JMSListener and @Consume annotations?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms

I am trying to consume JMS messages sent via spring JmsTemplate using @Consume annotated bean. The consumer is not receiving messages when sent using JmsTemplate.

Whereas, when sent using ProducerTemplate of Camel the messages are received.

What is the difference between @org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener and @org.apache.camel.Consume?

Producer Logic

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("jms:mailbox", message);
```

Consumer Logic

```
@Consume(uri="jms:mailbox")
    public void onRequest(String name) {
        System.out.println("Received message > "+name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Camel [`@Consume`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/parameter-binding-annotations.html) annotation can consume from any [endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/endpoint.html), which supports consuming. **This annotation takes [`uri`](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/uris.html) as parameter**. URI consists of scheme, path and optional params. In case of [JMS component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) the scheme is `jms`, path is [`Destination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Destination.html) (in your case `mailbox`) and params are additional options customizing behavior of `Consumer`.

Spring [`@JmsListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) can consume from JMS and **takes [`Destination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Destination.html) as parameter**.

Your code does not work because the `Destination` is `mailbox`, not `jms:mailbox`. Spring [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) does not know about `jms` scheme, it is Camel specific. So use `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("mailbox", message)` on Spring side and `@Consume(uri="jms:mailbox")` on Camel side.